# Xamarin Forms Store downloaded images into BundleResource (iOS), EmbeddedResource (Android) or Content(UWP)

Tags: xamarin.forms, storage

I would like to save downloaded images into the respective platforms "PCL" storage location. "PCL" storage location means as BundleResource on iOS, EmbeddedResource on Android or Content on UWP.
Instead of putting these images into the Xamarin.Forms during compiled time, I hope to download these images only when users needed them.  This will reduce the app overall size during installation.
Is there a way to do so?  Thanks.

Comment: the application bundle on iOS and Android (not sure about UWP) is read only.  If you want to save files at runtime, you have to store them in user writable folders.  Downloading images at runtime and displaying them in your app is completely doable.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=macos

Comment: In Xamarin.Forms, the Image.Source by default is coded to retrieve local images in each platform.  If I store the downloaded images into user app location (ms-appdata), I am unable to specify the correct ImageSource.FromFile to obtain these dowloaded images in iOS, Android and UWP.

Comment: you would need to dynamically assign a FileImageSource as you downloaded your images.  You could also use FFImageLoading to manage this.  Or just specify the image sources as urls